# Service Bus for Windows Server

Tags: servicebus

I am trying to host WCF services on an on-premise Service Bus but I understand that relaying is not yet supported. Is there a scheduled release date for this functionality?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we'd need a crystal ball to predict the future

Answer (score 1):

Relay feature will not be supported in Service Bus Server in near future. 
The customer segment for this feature is very less in Server space - closer to Zero as Relaying is primarily to get data/services out of Enterprise (firewall) with out having to do heavyweight solutions like VPN.

HTH!
Sree

Answer (score 0):

According to [Clemens Vasters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560396/clemens-vasters), Architect, Azure Messaging: "If it's up to me then relay is also going to go into that new [[Azure Stack](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack/)] server". But it probably won't happen soon.

Reference: A May 12 Integrate 2016 talk titled [Service Bus – Roadmap, What’s next?](http://www.biztalk360.com/integrate-2016-resources/service-bus-roadmap-whats-next/). This statement was made at about 46:19. You can listen to announcements related to Service Bus for Windows Server at about 40:35 and you can read some paraphrased transcripts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769190/1703887).