# Is Azure Service Bus available on Azure Stack (on-premises)

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-stack

I'm currently running Windows Service Bus 1.1 via Azure Pack. This versions official support life ended Jan 2018, I need a long term on-premises Service Bus option.

Is Azure Service Bus available via the Azure Stack? Also looking for any recommended alternatives.

Thanks

re: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/collaboration-and-federation-azure-service-bus-messaging-on-premises-futures/

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is "no". Azure Service Bus is planned for Azure Stack, but is not available today. There's a [UserVoice thread](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/32076025-bring-event-hubs-and-service-bus-to-azure-stack) about this, but the messaging team doesn't interact a lot over UserVoice. You chances are better with trying Azure Support or their [twitter account](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport).